# N people sit at a round table, starting from #1, every other one leaves, who's the last one?

Tags: permutations

For example, there are 10 people sitting there.

So the 1st round, such people leave:
$$\#1, \#3, \#5, \#7, \#9$$
and remains
$$\#2, \#4, \#6, \#8, \#10$$

Then the 2nd round, such people leave:
$$\#2, \#6, \#10$$
and remains
$$\#4, \#8$$

Then the 3rd round, such people leave:
$$\#8$$
and remains
$$\#4$$

so the last one remained is #4.

If we note f(10)=4, how to get a general formula for f(N)?

Comment: For a more general problem of the same kind, please see the [Josephus Problem.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Josephus_problem)

Comment: so there's no close form for the general case $k!=2$?

Comment: None that I know. There is one for $k=2$.

Comment: got it, thanks! :)